# Is there a way to make find use shell's extglob shell option?

Tags: bash, shell, find, pattern-matching

In short, I instinctively wrote a command like this to find the two files `prefix.ext` and `prefix_suffix.ext` down a hierarchy

```bsh
find /some/path -type f -name 'prefix?(_suffix).zip'
```

but it doesn't work.

Since `man find`, under `-name patter` refers to pattern as a "shell pattern", I was wandering if one has control on which pattern should be used and, specifically if `extglob` option can be used.

Comment: In `zsh`, you can always use `**/prefix(_suffix|).zip(.)` and do without `find`. Note that `extglob` is a bash-specific option to enable a subset of ksh's extended globs, it's not anything standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`find` only uses “basic” shell patterns, [as described in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13). It doesn’t support `extglob`-style globs (even though the GNU implementation says it uses `fnmatch`, and [the GNU C library’s implementation of `fnmatch` supports extended patterns](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html)).

If you’re using GNU `find`, you can filter using regular expressions instead; see [the relevant section of the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Regular-Expressions.html) for details:

```
-regex '.*/prefix\(_suffix\)?\.zip'
```

with the default regular expression type, or

```
-regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/prefix(_suffix)?\.zip'
```

with EREs.

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out by others already, the `find` utility does not by default support extended globbing patterns as found in the `bash` shell and others (originally inherited from the `ksh` shell).

You may *use* the `bash` shell to perform these tests though:

```bsh
find /some/path -type f \
    -exec bash -O extglob -c '[[ ${1##*/} == prefix?(_suffix).zip ]]' bash {} \; \
    -print
```

This is terribly inefficient though, as you would need to spawn a `bash` process for each file that you want to investigate.  It would make more sense to rewrite the extended globbing pattern using one or several normal patterns:

```bsh
find /some/path -type f \
    \( -name prefix.zip -o -name prefix_suffix.zip \) \
    -print
```

This has the benefit of being portable and easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer mentioned regular expressions, which made me think of an obvious solution: using `-regex` instead of `-name`:

```bsh
find /some/path -type f -regex '.*/prefix\(_suffix\)?\.zip'
```

I suspect it might be slower, but maybe not so much.

Comment: Accepting the other answer based on the level of detail that it provides.